# OpenJPA: Persisting new entity with a list of new entities

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, openjpa

I have the following model: A *-> B. (onedirectional onetomany)

When I retrieve an A, create a new B, add that B to A, persist A and commit the transaction. B is saved correctly.

When I however, create a new A, create a new B, add that B to A, persist A and commit the transaction. B is saved, but the foreign key on the table B to the table A is not filled in. (so the relationship between A and B is not persisted)

Can anyone explain what I do wrong?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`ORDER`")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name="FK_ORDER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    public List<ProductOrder> productOrders = new ArrayList<>();

    public Order(){}
}

public class ProductOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public ProductOrder(){}
}
```

//calling code

```
@Path("/orders")
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class OrderResource { 

     @PersistenceContext
     private EntityManager entityManager;

     @Path("/make")
     @POST
     @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public Response makeOrder(){
         Order o = new Order();
         o.productOrders.add(new ProductOrder());
         entityManager.persist(o);
         //result The order and the productOrder are saved in the database, but the             foreign key to order in the productOrder tabel is not filled in
     }

     @Path("/updateForTesting")
     @POST
     @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public Response updateOrder(String orderId){
         Order o = entityManager.find(Order.class, orderId);
         o.productOrders.add(new ProductOrder());
         entityManager.persist(o);
         //result The productOrder is saved to the database with the foreign key filled in
     }
}
```

Comment: Should show us the code and config you tried so far!

Comment: @JoinColumn(name="FK_ORDER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
public List<ProductOrder> productOrders = new ArrayList<>();



...

Order o = new Order;
o.productOrders.add(new ProductOrder();
entityManager.persist(o);

Comment: It would be nice if you updated the question with something that is more readable.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize I could edit the question

Answer (score -1):

Correct would be: create a new A, create a new B, **persist B (and retrieve it)**, add that B to A, persist A

Comment: Not really, I have CascadeType.Persist on my collection

Comment: @robisrob it would be helpful if you edit your question, paste in Entites and Beans executed. Posting code in comments doesn't help much.